# htaccess 301 redirect all website pages with query to /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

In the past website was full of pages with different basis. After redisign and with new concept the website consists of only 1 page. So I need to redirect all old pages to /.

Pages for example:

```
http://domain.com/catalog/index.html?c_id=145 
http://domain.com/catalog/?c_id=116
http://domain.com/news/read.html?id=174
and so on.
```

In htaccess I've made several rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog(.*)$ http://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

But this rule don't give a full control, and the result is not satisfactory:

```
http://domain.com/?c_id=145
```

How can I get rid of this? I need to redirect all such links to `http://domain.com` without any additions. I think the {QUERY_STRING} can help, but I don't know how to do this correct.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `?` at the end to create a blank query string:

```
#                       append "?" here ----v
RewriteRule ^catalog(.*)$ http://domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```